# Monitor how much public traffic usage with iftop on a aws vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, network-monitoring

I'm trying to identify what is spending so much traffic on my AWS machine using iftop.

The problem is, apparently, ec2 instances don't have a public interface, so iftop only monitors the private ip at `eth0`.

I need to identify what hosts are connecting to my machine and how much traffic they are generating in an arbitrary time-frame. How can I do that at AWS without a public interface?

Answer (score 0):

That traffic is all on the private interface.  For instances with public IP addresses, the VPC Internet Gateway translates public to private and back, at the network border.

Comment: So, how would I distinguish private from public traffic? Any tools for that?